# Facebook permissions for an app which should tag/mention/post to user feed without friendship

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

We are a event company which offers a system for improving social media performance for companies on events.

F.e. a user registers via internet for an event (f.e. a concert, sponsored by a big brand company). During the registration process, the user has to grant permission to our facebook app (so we can tag/mention or post on his feed with his name, or he just has to like our page), otherwise he is not allowed to visit the concert.

we want now to do following:

1. after registration finished, we would like to post on the user
   wall or mention the user in a post by our app:

   f.e. "Max Mustermann: Hey, i just visited this concert #brandname"
   (as post on the user feed by the user himself) or: "Max Mustermann
   visited the Concert of #brandname" (as story or mention)
2. We also offer a system to make pictures and the pictures are
   associated with the users (they can select that he is the user on
   the photo). After the user selects that its him on the photo, the
   photo should be shared on facebook, either by the user himself or
   tagged by our app).

Is there any best practices to to these things? We implemented a workflow already, but facebook said that this doesnt work.

I cannot find anything usefull, the docs are not going deep enough to find out which rights are needed for which action type (user feed post, tag or mention or story)...

Can you give me some advice on how to do it proberly?

Comment: _“the user has to grant permission to our facebook app (so we can tag/mention or post on his feed with his name, or he just has to like our page), otherwise he is not allowed to visit the concert”_ – that’s a violation of platform policies. You are not allowed to incentivize sharing/posting in any way, and like-gating is also not allowed any more. And every single character of a message posted via your app has to be typed by the user – you are not allowed to pre-fill it, or even “add” your hashtag to it.

Comment: Yeah i also read this... So isnt there any possibility to create an equal workflow? if not, facebook is getting really useless for company driven events like i mentioned..?

Comment: Make it optional for users to share or like – if they want to, they do it, and if they don’t want to, they don’t. Don’t _blackmail_ them into doing so by not letting them attend your event if they don’t. And if you want to transport additional information with their own user-generated message, then let them post a link to your page, that has appropriate OG information set via meta tags.

Comment: yeah but who wants to share something, unless he has some advantages from it? if he doesnt get more than a not sharing user, why should he do it? also some of our companies dont want to make events, if the outcome is low (related to facebook performance)... And another question: can I tag/mention a user (outgoing from an app or page), which i dont have a frienship with? Can I enforce making friendship with my app/page? Or is this also forbidden?

Comment: Users share content that they find interesting or funny or […] – so create content that is, and users will share it :-) / Only users can be friends, there is no “friendship” between users and apps or pages. / Only friends can be tagged in posts made via API, not random users. And the user making the post has to select the friends they want to tag him-/herself as well, your app can not chose them automatically.

Comment: Hm i see... And would it be allowed, that all users participate the concert, but if you connect via facebook and share a link you get a extra drink for free? or is this extra favoritism also forbidden? (thanks a lot for your answers, i will mark an answer if you provide something below!)

Comment: Not, that is also not allowed. I’ll sum this up in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook’s [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) forbids almost every kind of “rewarding” users for making posts, sharing, giving likes, etc.

> 4. Encourage proper use
>
>    5. Only incentivize a person to log into your app, like your app’s Page, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions. (Effective November 5th, 2014, you may no longer incentivize people to like your app's Page).

This basically means that you can not reward a user in any way for actions such as sharing/posting, liking etc. It does not even matter whether the reward is of a “physical” nature (money, gifts, free drinks, …), or just “immaterial” in the form of some “points” system or the like.

Facebook wants users to share and like content of their own free will, because they *feel* like sharing or liking that piece of content – *“hey, this is funny/interesting/etc., I’ll share that with my friends because I know they also like that kind of stuff”* – and not because they get any kind of reward for it; simply because that creates a lot of “unwanted” posts/likes – post and likes that users would not have made/given, if their was no reward tied to this. Those kinds of posts are the ones that annoy a user’s friends the most, and are often reported as spam.